# Passing address, but it is working like call by value in C?

Tags: c, pointers, call-by-value

Hello I am a beginner in C programming language. Recently I read about call by value and call by address. I have learned that in call by address changes in the called functions reflects the callee. However the following code does not work like that.

```
int x = 10,y = 20;
void change_by_add(int *ptr) {
    ptr = &y;
    printf("\n Inside change_by_add\t %d",*ptr);
    // here *ptr is printing 20
}

void main(){
    int *p;
    p = &x;
    change_by_add(p);
    printf("\nInside main\t %d", *p);
    // here *p is still pointing to address of x and printing 10
}
```

When I am passing address then why the changes made by called function does not reflect caller?

Comment: down voters please mention ur comments, it tough question for me (as i am a beginner) hopefully now for u.

Comment: Please use the code button to format your code. With the number of questions you've asked, you really should know this by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is assigning a new address to the pointer but the pointer itself is being passed by value, as all arguments are in C. To change the value of a pointer variable the address of the pointer itself must be passed:

```
void change_by_add(int **ptr)
{
    *ptr = &y;
}

change_by_add(&p);
```

See [C FAQ Question 4.8](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html).

Passing by reference does not exist in C but can be achieved by passing the address of the variable who's value is to be changed to a function. For example:

```
void add_to_int(int* a_value, int a_increment)
{
    *a_value += a_increment;
}
```

Comment: There is a typo `*ptr = y`

Comment: @LumpN, nope. `y` is an `int` and `*ptr` is an `int*`.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply setting the value of the pointer in the function, not the value of the pointed to variable.  The function should use the following code:

*ptr = y;

This derefences the pointer (exposing the value pointed to), and therefore when you use the equals operator, the memory pointed at is modified, not the pointer itself.  I hope this helps to clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

Changes made by called function does not get reflected by the caller because **you are overriding the pointer address in the called function** i.e `ptr = &y;`.

Initially, you passed the address of `x` but you are changing it with the address of `y`.

If you really want to implement the concept of call by address then **change value instead of address**.

Example:

```
void change_by_add(int *ptr) {
    *ptr = y;  //changing value
    printf("\nInside change_by_add\t %d",*ptr);
}

void main(){
    int *p;
    p = &x;
    change_by_add(p);
    printf("\nInside main\t %d \n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Inside change_by_add     20
Inside main  20
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as call by address in C. There is only call by value. What one does when a function needs to modify an argument in a way that is visible to the caller is to have the caller pass a pointer to something, and have the called function write the update though that pointer. Note that the pointer itself is still sent as call-by-value - that is: the called function gets its own copy of the pointer and could change it to point to anything else if it wants to.