# Return two pointers from a function in c

Tags: c, pointers

I know that you can return a pointer to the first element of an array in c by doing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *my_func(void);

int main(void)
{
    int *a;
    int i;

    a = my_func();

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    free(a);

    return 0;
}

int *my_func(void)
{
    int *array;
    int i;

    array = calloc(3, sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    return array;
}
```

But if I wanted to return two pointers instead of just one, I tried:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *my_func(int *);

int main(void)
{
    int *a;
    int *b;
    int i;

    a = my_func(b);

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
        printf("b[%d] = %d\n", i, b[i]);
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);

    return 0;
}

int *my_func(int *array2)
{
    int *array;
    int i;

    array = calloc(3, sizeof(int));
    array2 = calloc(3, sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
        array2[i] = i;
    }

    return array;
}
```

But this seg faults on the printf for b. I ran it through valgrind and it says that there is an invalid read of size 4 at the printf for b, which means I'm doing something screwy with the b pointer. I was just wondering what the best way to "return" a second pointer to an array was in c? I'm asking because I would like to do it this way rather than use a global variable (I'm not opposed to them, as they are useful at times, I just prefer not to use them if possible). The other questions I've seen on this site used statically allocated arrays, but I haven't yet stumbled across a question that was using dynamic allocation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `int *array2` --> `int **array2`, `*array2 = calloc(3, sizeof(int));`, `(*array2)[i] = i;` and `a = my_func(&b);`

Comment: There are many results if you google the question title. Even closer if you put "stackoverflow" in there too.

Comment: [Passing address, but it is working like call by value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291591/passing-address-but-it-is-working-like-call-by-value-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of three (and a half) simple ways to return multiple items of any kind from a C-function. The ways are described below. It looks like a lot of text, but this answer is mostly code, so read on:

1. Pass in an output argument as you have done, but do it correctly. You have to allocate space for an `int *` in `main()` and then pass the pointer to that to `my_func`.

   In `main()`:

   ```
   a = my_func(&b);
   ```

   `my_func()` becomes:

   ```
   int *my_func(int **array2)
   {
       int *array;
       int i;

       array = calloc(3, sizeof(int));
       *array2 = calloc(3, sizeof(int));

       for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
           array[i] = i;
           (*array2)[i] = i;
       }

       return array;
   }
   ```
2. Make your function allocate array of two pointers to the `int` arrays you are trying to allocate. This will require an additional allocation of two `int` pointers, but may be worth the trouble.

   `main()` then becomes:

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
       int **ab;
       int i;

       ab = my_func(b);

       for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
           printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, ab[0][i]);
           printf("b[%d] = %d\n", i, ab[1][i]);
       }

       free(ab[0]);
       free(ab[1]);
       free(ab);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   `my_func()` then becomes:

   ```
   int **my_func(void)
   {
       int **arrays;
       int i, j;

       arrays = calloc(2, sizeof(int *));
       arrays[0] = calloc(3, sizeof(int));
       arrays[1] = calloc(3, sizeof(int));

       for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
       {
           for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           {
               arrays[j][i] = i;
           }
       }

       return arrays;
   }
   ```
3. Return a structure or structure pointer. You will need to define the structure, and decide whether you want to return the structure itself, a newly allocated pointer to it, or pass it in as a pointer and have `my_func()` fill it in for you.

   The structure definition would look something like this:

   ```
   struct x
   {
       int *a;
       int *b;
   }
   ```

   You would then rephrase your current functions as one of the following three options:

   1. Direct passing of structure (not recommended for general use):

      ```
      int main(void)
      {
          struct x ab;
          int i;

          ab = my_func();

          for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          {
              printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, ab.a[i]);
              printf("b[%d] = %d\n", i, ab.b[i]);
          }

          free(ab.a);
          free(ab.b);

          return 0;
      }

      struct x my_func(void)
      {
          struct x ab;
          int i;

          ab.a = calloc(3, sizeof(int));
          ab.b = calloc(3, sizeof(int));

          for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          {
              ab.a[i] = i;
              ab.b[i] = i;
          }

          return ab;
      }
      ```
   2. Return a pointer to a dynamically allocated structure (this is a pretty good option in general):

      ```
      int main(void)
      {
          struct x *ab;
          int i;

          ab = my_func();

          for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          {
              printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, ab->a[i]);
              printf("b[%d] = %d\n", i, ab->b[i]);
          }

          free(ab->a);
          free(ab->b);
          free(ab);

          return 0;
      }

      struct x *my_func(void)
      {
          struct x *ab;
          int i;

          ab = malloc(sizeof(struct x));
          ab->a = calloc(3, sizeof(int));
          ab->b = calloc(3, sizeof(int));

          for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          {
              ab->a[i] = i;
              ab->b[i] = i;
          }

          return ab;
      }
      ```
   3. Allocate the structure in `main()` and fill it in in `my_func` via a passed-in pointer. This option is often used in a way where `my_func` would allocate the structure if you pass in a `NULL` pointer, otherwise it would return whatever you passed in. The version of `my_func` shown here has no return value for simplicity:

      ```
      int main(void)
      {
          struct x ab;
          int i;

          my_func(&ab);

          for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          {
              printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, ab.a[i]);
              printf("b[%d] = %d\n", i, ab.b[i]);
          }

          free(ab.a);
          free(ab.b);

          return 0;
      }

      void my_func(struct x *ab)
      {
          int i;

          ab->a = calloc(3, sizeof(int));
          ab->b = calloc(3, sizeof(int));

          for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          {
              ab->a[i] = i;
              ab->b[i] = i;
          }

          return;
      }
      ```

For all the examples shown here, don't forget to update the declaration of `my_func` at the top of the file, although I am sure any reasonable compiler will remind you if you forget.

Keep in mind also that these are just three options I pulled out of my brain at a moments notice. While they are likely to cover 99% of any use cases you may come up against any time soon, there are (probably lots of) other options out there.

Comment: @DavidBowling. Let me know if my fix is acceptable.

Comment: I think that is fine; just want to avoid confusion of pointer == array language. Also, arrays can't be returned from functions.

Comment: @DavidBowling. I agree that technical accuracy is important.

Answer (score 1):

Function parameters are its local variables. Functions deal with copies of values of the supplied arguments.

You can imagine your function definition and its call the following way

```
a = my_func(b);


int *my_func( /* int *array2 */ )
{
    int *array2 = b;
    //...
}
```

So any changes of the local variable `array2` inside the function do not influence on the original argument `b`.

For such a function definition you have to pass the argument by reference that is the function should be declared like

```
int *my_func( int **array2 );
                  ^^
```

There are many ways to implement the function. You could define a structure of two pointers as for example

```
struct Pair
{
    int *a;
    int *b;
};
```

and use it as the return type of the function

```
struct Pair my_func( void );
```

Another approach is to pass to the function an array of pointers to the original pointers.

The function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t multiple_alloc( int ** a[], size_t n, size_t m )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) *a[i] = NULL;

    size_t k = 0;

    for ( ; k < n && ( *a[k] = malloc( m * sizeof( int ) ) ) != NULL; k++ )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) ( *a[k] )[i] = i;
    }

    return k;
}

#define N   2
#define M   3

int main(void) 
{
    int *a;
    int *b;

    multiple_alloc( ( int ** [] ) { &a, &b }, N, M );

    if ( a )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    if ( b )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ ) printf( "%d ", b[i] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( a );
    free( b );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 
0 1 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the compound literal should pass without some explanation for OP....

Comment: @DavidBowling He can ask a corresponding question.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *my_func(int **);

int main(void)
{
    int *a;
    int *b;
    int i;

    b=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

    a = my_func(&b);


    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
        printf("b[%d] = %d\n", i, b[i]);
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);

    return 0;
}

int *my_func(int **array2)
{
    int *array;
    int i;


    array = calloc(3, sizeof(int));
    *array2 =calloc(3,sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
        *((*array2)+i)=i;//or (*array2)[i]

    }

    return array;
}
```

Pass the pointer by reference. Because its the same logic as, to manipulate an integer block you need to pass a pointer to it. Similarly, to manipulate a pointer, you will have to pass a pointer to it(i.e. pointer to pointer).